# Batch file to open, edit and save an input text file for the execution of a python script

Tags: python-2.7, batch-file

I'm running a python script which takes input from the user using a text file `input.txt`. The file `input.txt` contains parameters in the following format:

```
username=abc123
male=0
female=1
email=abc123@gmail.com
```

Trying to make it user friendly (keeping in mind that only a text file input is accepted), I would like the user to :

1. double click on a .bat file (which would open `input.txt`)
2. enter the values for parameters (after "=" above) and modify `input.txt` to suit his execution
3. save `input.txt`
4. close `input.txt`

Now, the .bat file should continue with the execution of the python script (taking inputs from the modified `input.txt` parameters) on the command prompt. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `start /wait notepad.exe input.txt` - user will be responsilble to save.

Comment: @Stephan So, with this, while the user is editing `input.txt`, the script halts and after he saves it, the python script will be executed right?

Comment: the script continues, when notepad gets closed. If this overstrains the users, build `input.txt` from scratch with your batch file (`set /p "name=Enter username: "` etc. to ask for the data and `echo username=%name%>>input.txt` etc. to write it to the file.